# How to change the lint directory in a vue.js app?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, eslint, vue-cli

I'm in the process of setting up Vue.js within an existing PHP application.  Since the PHP application has an existing directory structure, I'm having to change up some of the default locations found in Vue Inspect using the vue.config.js file. The vue portion of the site I want to lint is kept in:

```
/src/vue-app
```

When running "npm run lint" it looks in everything under "/src".  How do I tell the linter to only look in "/src/vue-app"? My vue.config.js file looks something like this currently:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  // options...
  baseUrl: 'https://local.my-site.com/dist/vue-app',
  outputDir: '/sites/my-site/public/dist/vue-app',
  configureWebpack: config => {
    return {
      entry: {
        app: './src/vue-app/main.js'
      },
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/vue-app')
        }
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        return [{
          template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/vue-app/index-default.phtml'),
          filename: path.resolve(__dirname, './sites/my-app/module/Dash/view/dash/index.phtml')
        }]
      })
  }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have the following configured in my package.json file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e"
  },
```

And this...

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

So while I wish there was an easier way for this to be configured, I figured out a path forward on my own project:

1. Vue CLI project lives in `/src/webapp/`
2. `.eslintrc` and `.prettierrc` live in `src/webapp`
3. `package.json` lives in root directory `/`

So to make the command `vue-cli-service lint` only target my Vue CLI directory. The resulting definition is:

`vue-cli-service lint ./src/webapp/**/*.js ./src/webapp/**/*.vue`

Hope this helps other people out there!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

`vue-cli-service lint ./src/vue-app`

As simple as this

Answer (score -1):

You can change your lint command from package.json to include your directory. E.g.

"lint": "eslint src/vue-app",

See command line [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/3.0.0/user-guide/command-line-interface#options)

Comment: Interesting.  I added what I have set in my package.json file.  I'm using the vue-cli-service to run lint.  Is there something I can set in the eslintConfig?

Comment: @AdamYoungers afaik there no such option in eslintConfig. But u can pass same option to vue-cli-service and it will work. For example my command:

    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --ignore-path .gitignore src tests",